# make hover on <li>item</li> change text colour too... CSS trick?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have some menu bars, and at the moment, the Background changes to black when hovering over an

```
 <li>content</li>
```

and the text changes from black to white when it is hovered over.

I need to make it so the text color changes when the whole `<li>content</li>` is hovered, not just when the the text is highlighted.

**here is the css**

```
 <style type="text/css">
    body{margin:0px; font-family:Tahoma, Sans-Serif; font-size:13px;}
    /* dock */
    #dock{margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style:none; position:fixed; top:0px; height:100%; 
          z-index:100; background-color:; left:0px;}
    #dock > li {width:40px; height:120px; margin: 0 0 1px 0; background-color:#;
                 background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:left center;}

    #dock #Menu {background-image:url(Menu.png);}

    #dock > li:hover {background-position:-40px 0px;}

    /* panels */
    #dock ul li {padding:5px; border: solid 0px #879b17;}
    #dock ul li:hover {padding:5px;
background:#879b17 url(item_bkg.png) repeat-x;
border: solid 0x #879b17;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000;
 }
    #dock ul li.header, #dock ul li .header:hover {
background:#fff url(header_bkg.png) repeat-x;
border:solid 10px #879b17;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
color: #FFF;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
 }

    #dock > li:hover ul {
display:block;
color: #FFF;
 }
    #dock > li ul {position:absolute; top:0px; left:-180px;  z-index:-1;width:180px; display:none;
                   background-color:#fff; border:solid 10px #000; border-top-left-radius: 20px; border-top-right-radius: 20px; padding:0px; margin:0px; list-style:none;}
    #dock > li ul.docked { display:block;z-index:-2;}

    .dock,.undock{}
   .undock {display:none; }
    #content {margin: 10px 0 0 60px; }

     body,td,th {
color: #333;
 }
 a:link {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
 }
 a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #FFF;
 }
 a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
 }
     #dock #Menu .free .header .dock {
color: #FFF;
font-weight: bold;
 }
     #dock #Menu .free .header .undock {
color: #FFFFFF;
 }
</style>
```

**and here is the HTML**

```
 <li id="Menu">
             <ul class="free">
               <li class="header"><a href="#" class="dock">DOCK</a><a href="#"      class="undock">UN-DOCK</a></li>
                 <li> </li>
               <li class="header">CAMPAIGNS</li>
                 <li><a href="#">Link Data</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>                
                 <li><a href="#">Summary Sheet</a></li>                                
               <li><a href="#">Add New Client</a></li>
               <li class="header">LINKS</li>
                 <li><a href="#">Record Transactions</a></li>
               <li class="header">REPORTS</li>
                 <li><a href="#">Handover Sheets</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Handover Summary</a></li>
               <li class="header" >MAINTENANCE</li>
                 <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Manage Users</a></li>                
           </ul>
         </li>
```

Thanks in advance if you are able to help

Regards

Henry

Comment: How do you know when a list item is "selected"?

Comment: I hope this is a snippet of your HTML because an `<li>` but be inside a `<ul>` - so your `#Menu` should either be a `<div>` or make sure it's inside opening and closing `<ul>`

Comment: I don't mean selected, but hovered over

Comment: `li:hover` always reacts on `li` being `hover`ed. Make sure your `li` is where you think it is and has the size you think it has.

Comment: for example, hovering over "Link Data" means
<BackGround goes from white to black and text goes from black to white>
But hovering over <li><a href="#">Link Data</a></li> turns background to black, but doesn't link as such...

Its like the HTML link of the text needs to be expanded to the whole <li>atribute</li>

Comment: Anchor elements are `display:inline` by default. Changing to `display:block` will make the anchor fill the space inside the `<li>`. Not sure how this will affect the rest of your layout though, without coding up a demo.

Comment: http://test.insideclients.co.uk/testmenu/

Here is a link to an old version of the menu bar I am playing around with...

Comment: Perhaps you want `li:hover a` instead of `a:hover`

Comment: can you see how selecting to list item changes BG, but only the text is linked..

I tried moving the <a href='#'><li> so the list item was in the link, but then the text doesnt change to white at all, but the whole List item is linked

Comment: ahh possibly, lets have a look...

Comment: Don't put `<a>` tags around the `<li>` tags, this is wrong in HTML. Keep it how you have it posted above.

Comment: looking at the code, everything is display:block

Comment: @HenryAspden I cannot see `<a>` set to `display:block` in your code above or in the example link

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'd recommend making the hover work on the 'A' elements instead of the LI elements.

In order to make the LI elements flly clickable you need to set the 'A' element within it to display:block (or inline-block) as 'A' tags are display:inline by default.

SO...

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">My Link</a></li>
</ul>

ul li a {
 display:block;
}

ul li a:hover, ul li a:focus {
 color:red;
}
```

Comment: I added the code in like so  
'#dock ul li a {dsiplay:block;}'

no such luck

Comment: @Billy Moat - I suppose it depends on the effect that you wish to invoke.

Comment: Did you literally type it in as 'dsiplay'? If so that's wrong it should be 'display'.

Comment: yes that was it @BillyMoat haha... me = total douche... thanks for everybodies help !!!! LEGENDS !!

Comment: now if any androiders fancy writing a quick activity for me that would be great haha

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231868/android-app-take-photo-select-photo-and-send-via-email#comment18024332_13231868

Answer (score 10):

I found that if you use padding for the "a" instead of the "li" it works well. By blocking out the padding you can then hover over the padded area within the div and the "a" links inside (that are padded) will hover a color of their own.

```
ul li a{
color:#ead6b7;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
padding:16px;
}

ul{
list-style-type:none;
}

li{
display:inline-block;
}

ul li a:hover{
color:#332419;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
}

li:hover{
background-color:#ead6b7;
}
```