# Change text color when hovered over li

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to change the text color of links when an `<li>` element is hovered over. Right now I have

```
#nav li a:hover {
  margin-left: -10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #13118C;
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
  margin-left: -10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #13118C;
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
}
```

However, this only changes the text color when the link itself is hovered over. If the mouse is slightly to the right of the link, the background changes but the text does not. I'd like it so that the mouse being to the right of the link is functionally the same as it being on the link itself. Is there a way to have the text color change when the background does?

Comment: I believe your question has already been [answered here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233878/make-hover-on-liitem-li-change-text-colour-too-css-trick?rq=1 "This is answered here.")

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Then ensure that either the `a` inherits its colour from its parent:

```css
li:hover a {
    color: inherit;
}
```

Or specify a selector to explicitly apply the same colour to the `a` element:

```css
#nav ul li:hover,
#nav ul li:hover a {
  margin-left: -10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #13118C;
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You could, of course, also make the `a` fill the `li` element, using:

```css
#nav ul li a {
    display: block;
}
```

If you specify a height for the `li`, then use that same height (with the previous `display: block` rule) the `a` will be vertically-centred within the `li` as well, for example:

```css
#nav ul li {
    height: 2em; /* or whatever, adjust to taste... */
}
#nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
}
```

Though the `padding` of the `li` won't be included within the specified height (it'll be the height of the element, plus the padding plus the border-width), so there'll be an empty-space around the `a`, unless you specify (for compliant browsers) `box-sizing: border-box;` to include the `border` and `padding` in the specified height.

Comment: Wow. Nice use of CSS I didn't know about (I'm a total noob).

Comment: Well, I hope I've helped! And don't worry, we all started learning somewhere. And most of us, me included, are *still* learning... =)

Comment: @DavidThomas Not *most*... **all** :)

Comment: li:hover a {
    color: inherit;
} 

worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, when you are giving your padding, try not to give it to li element but give it to anchor element to avoid this kind of confusion. Of course, do not forget to apply `display: block` property to the anchor element.

Answer (score 5):

Easy!

```
#nav li a {
  color: white;
}

/* When hovering over li, apply styles to child a */
#nav li:hover a {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of good suggestions above, but I wanted to mention the reason why your CSS rules did not work, which is because of specificity. Each CSS selector you define has a calculated specificity, which you can read about here. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity. Those values are used to determine which rules take precedence over others.

Note that inherited selectors have a specificity of 0, which is important in your case.

```
#nav ul li { color: #000; }
#nav ul li a { color: #800; }      // This has a specificity of 103 when applied to <A> elements
#nav ul li:hover { color: #080; }  // This has a specificity of 0 when applied to <A> elements because it is inherited from the parent <LI> element.
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rg4fN/

By appending an `a` element to the last selector, it will no longer be inherited when applied to  elements. It now has a higher specificity than the other selectors and thus will take precedence.

```
#nav ul li a { color: #800; }        // This has a specificity of 103 when applied to <A> elements 
#nav ul li:hover a { color: #080; }  // This has a specificity of 113 when applied to <A> elements
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NxT29/

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like this

```
 #nav li a 
{
  margin-left: -10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #13118C;
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;

}
```

apply styles to child a

```
#nav li:hover a 
{
 margin-left: -10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 background-color: #13118C; 
 font-weight: bold;
 width: 100%;
 color: blue;
 }
```