# I'm writing code to help me hover over my drop down list without clicking of coure

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="atpcontent">
        <div class="ajdrop">
            <h2>Related Links</h2>
                <div class="aanswer">
                <p><a href="#" target="_blank">STE</a></p>
                <p><a href="#" target="_blank">Foiicoi</a></p>
                <p><a href="#" target="_blank">FAC</a></p>
                <p><a href="#" target="_blank">SAC</a></p>
                </div>
        </div><!--close jdrop-->
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.atpcontent{
    background-color:#bbb;
    padding:10px 10px;
    font-size:1em;
    }
.atpcontent h2{
    padding:0;
    font-family:'raleway', arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:1.5em;
    font-weight:600;
    color:#0e4373;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }
.atpcontent p{
    padding:7px 0;
    color:#0e4373;
    font-size:1em;
    font-family:'raleway',arial,sans-serif;}
.atpcontent img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;}
.atpcontent a{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:inherit;
    transition:1s;}
.atpcontent a:hover{
    color:#06C;
    transition:1s;
    }
.ajdrop{word-wrap:break-word;padding-bottom:10px;}
.ajdrop p{
    padding:7px 0;
    font-family:'raleway', arial, sans-serif;
    color:#0e4373;
    font-size:1em;}
/* dropdown arrow sections css */
.ajdrop h2{
    background: url(assets/img/down.png) no-repeat 0 12px; /*comment this if you dont want arrows*/
    padding:9px 0 0 20px;
    font-family:'raleway', arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#0e4373;}
.ajdrop h2.close{background-image: url(assets/img/up.png);

}/*comment this if you dont want arrows*/
.aanswer{margin-left:35px;}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make hover on <li>item</li> change text colour too... CSS trick?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233878/make-hover-on-liitem-li-change-text-colour-too-css-trick)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to use ul and li

If you're considering using those tags, use this code as well

`ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}`

place this in your css

I hope to have answered your question with this.